# Cell array expansion Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a cell array which looks like this :

```
                        double              strings               strings
{ 1 x 3,cell} = { {1000000 x 1, double} {1000000 x 1, cell} {1000000 x 1, cell} }
```

And I want to convert this to a dataset using `cell2dataset()`. So, I need to expand all the cell arrays and put them into one cell so that I could use `cell2dataset()`.

But I cannot seem to expand this `{ 1 x 3 }` into a `{ 1000000 x 3 }` cell array.

Any ideas as to how to do this?

Comment: `horzcat(input_cell_array{:})`?

Comment: `Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being
concatenated are not consistent.`

Comment: Its because some are double arrays and some are string arrays, I think.

Comment: Maybe there are some empty cells in there?

Comment: @Nishanth Can you provide say a five row example of your data (try make it as representative as possible)?

Answer (score 0):

try this: given `'a'` is your input cell array of size `{1 X 3}`

```
b=cell(size(a{1,1},1),size(a,2));
b(:,1)=num2cell(a{1,1});
b(:,2)=a{1,2};
b(:,3)=a{1,3};
ds=cell2dataset(b,'VarNames',{'Observation','attribute_1','attribute_2'});
```

It seems to be a crude method, but it works. Any further improvement is welcome.